# Object of Singletons

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way of creating an object of Singletons? I have a class which will be shared between different applications. This class should be a singleton PER application.

Here is what I currently have. However, when I instantiate `app1` twice, it creates a new instance for that.

```js
class Sample {
  constructor(appName) { // eslint-disable-line
    if (!Sample._instance[appName]) {
      Sample._instance[appName] = this
      console.log('Creating new instance')
      this.counter = 0
    }
    return Sample._instance[appName]
  }

  getVal () {
    this.counter++
    console.log('counter: ' + this.counter)
  }
}
```

Then I call it like this:

```
import Sample from './sample'


const sample1 = new Sample('app1')
sample1.getVal() // OK - prints 1
sample1.getVal() // OK - prints 2

const sample1a = new Sample('app1')
sample1a.getVal() // NOK - prints 1 - should print 3

const sample2 = new Sample('app2')
sample2.getVal() // OK - prints 1
sample2.getVal() // OK - prints 2
```

If instead I do something like below, then how can I actually pass in `appName` when the instance is created already during `import`?

```js
const sample = new Sample(appName)
export default sample
```

Answer (score 0):

Just adding `static _instance = {}` got rid of the runtime error I encountered and made it work as you want.

I also tested this in nodejs to make sure there's not anything weird going on when importing the class instead of declaring it in the same file.

```js
class Sample {
  static _instance = {};

  constructor(appName) { // eslint-disable-line
    if (!Sample._instance[appName]) {
      Sample._instance[appName] = this
      console.log('Creating new instance')
      this.counter = 0
    }
    return Sample._instance[appName]
  }

  getVal () {
    this.counter++
    console.log('counter: ' + this.counter)
  }
}

const sample1 = new Sample('app1')
sample1.getVal() // OK - prints 1
sample1.getVal() // OK - prints 2

const sample1a = new Sample('app1')
sample1a.getVal() // NOK - prints 1 - should print 3

const sample2 = new Sample('app2')
sample2.getVal() // OK - prints 1
sample2.getVal() // OK - prints 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate the roles of the container object and the singleton.

Below I made an IIFE singleton `container` that handles creating and storing new instances of `Sample` and it returns an existing instance if it's already stored.

You can keep the class definitions and container singleton in their own file and export the container. Since it's already invoked in the module, you just need to call `container.get('app')` in the importing scripts.

```js
class Sample {
  constructor() {
     console.log('Creating new instance')
     this.counter = 0
  }

  getVal () {
    this.counter++
    console.log('counter: ' + this.counter)
  }
}

const container = (() => {
  const singletons = {};
  
  const get = (appName) =>{
    if (!singletons[appName]){
      singletons[appName] = new Sample();
    }
      return singletons[appName]
  }
  return { get }
})();

let sample1 = container.get('app1')
sample1.getVal();
sample1.getVal();

let sample1A = container.get('app1')
sample1A.getVal();

let sample3 = container.get('app2')
sample3.getVal();
```